# get position of links within staticlayout

Tags: android, layout, html

Im using a StaticLayout to draw text from HTML onto a canvas.
What i need to figure out is how i can make links within the text clickable.
I figure the easiest way is to get the coordinates of the links within the text, and make 
a custom click event on the view.

This is what i god so far:

```
Spanned mySpannedHTML = Html.fromHtml(html_text, null, null);

StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(mySpannedHTML, mWhite, mWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

sl.draw(canvas);

//FINE SO FAR, but how to get the coorinates of the links?


//GETTING THE LINKS

URLSpan[] getUrls =((Spanned) sl.getText()).getSpans(0, sl.getText().length(), URLSpan.class);

for (URLSpan urlSpan : getUrls) {

                int start =((Spanned) sl.getText()).getSpanStart(urlSpan);
                int end =((Spanned) sl.getText()).getSpanEnd(urlSpan);

//LOG LINKS URL AND LINK TEXT

                Log.i("spans", "url: "+urlSpan.getURL() + " Link text: "+ ((Spanned) sl.getText()).subSequence(start, end) + " ");

            }
```

So, im really stuck here... The reason why i need the coordinates of the links within the text is because I am loading the canvas on to a openGL texture for rendering. Makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a function to pass the MotionEvent and View from the caller. Then I got the path of the urlSpan, get the bounds (see rectF) and add the offset to the rectangle (because my staticlayout wasn't covering the entire screen, and the rectF shows the location inside of the static layout)
The resulting rectF gives the bounds of the URLSpan.

```
 public boolean onTextTouched(View widget,MotionEvent event)
{
    //If the text contains an url, we check its location and if it is touched: fire the click event.
    Spanned spanned = (Spanned)text;
    URLSpan[] urls = spanned.getSpans(0,spanned.length(),URLSpan.class);
    for(int i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
    {
        //get the start and end points of url span
        int start=spanned.getSpanStart(urls[i]);
        int end=spanned.getSpanEnd(urls[i]);

        Path dest = new Path();
        mStaticLayout.getSelectionPath(start, end, dest);

        RectF rectF = new RectF();
        dest.computeBounds(rectF, true);

        //Add the left and top margins of your staticLayout here.
        rectF.offset(getContentLeft(),getContentTop());

        if(rectF.contains(event.getX(),event.getY()))
        {
            urls[i].onClick(widget);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the paint and use measureText to determine the x coordinates and then use the line number and ascent and descent to determine the y's.